# Creating a diagnostic memory dump of live erlang VM

Tags: erlang

[@lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201614/lukas) Recently, during an Erlang talk at IBM Bristol, you told my team member, [Mike Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2405601/mike-wallace), that there is a way to send an OS signal to a live Erlang VM so that a core dump of the Erlang VM is generated without killing the VM. I looked at all the material from your talk as well as Erlang documentation and didn't find the answer. The best I can find is the thread http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-February/077727.html. The responses from the threat talk about:

```
You can access these with process_info(Pid, messages) for the mailbox and
sys:get_state(Pid) for the state, respectively.

erlang:system_info(dist).   (distribution information)
erlang:system_info(info).   (misc system info)
erlang:system_info(loaded). (loaded module information)
erlang:system_info(procs).  (process heaps and stacktraces)

file:write_file("/tmp/procs.txt", erlang:system_info(info)).
```

Mike tried `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, but they both kill the beam.smp process. Can you please tell us the correct signal to use?